# How to Create Following Form

Tags: android

I am new in Android . I have to create following form in Android I search a lot and tried how to put Edit box and Button in Custom View at specify place but as such nothing fruit full .Need Suggestion to create below Form

[image]

> One Can view form here : https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B24mKxvBKwivcGtNSWZIOHpiSnc

Comment: try activity that looks like a dialog available in api demos

Comment: try making the view programatically thru JAVA class...

Comment: @AdityaNikhade I tired but in that how you place Edit box and button in between of view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this [Android Login and Registration Screen Design](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/)

This is very similar to your requirement